# Funciones de una clase como callbacks en OpenGL c++

Tags: c++, opengl

Me ha surgido un problema en la elaboración de un motor gráfico mediante OpenGL. El caso es que he definido la clase `DB`en la que implemento el método `initContext(int argc, char** argv)` en el cual debo realizar las correspondientes llamadas a los callbacks. El caso es que estos callbacks deben ser funciones sin miembro, y como intento introducirlos mediante funciones de la clase, estas son con miembro y da error. Me gustaría saber de qué forma se puede solucionar esto. Adjunto el código del `.h`y del `.cpp`

CÓDIGO DE `db.h`

```
#pragma once
#include "mesh.h"

class DB {
    std::vector<Mesh> modelos;
    std::vector<Programa> programas;
    Camara *camara;
public:
    DB();
    void initContext(int argc, char** argv);
    void initOGL();
    void mainLoop();
    void addMesh(Mesh modelo);
    void idle();
    void render();
    void resize(int width, int height);
    void mouse(int button, int state, int x, int y);
    void keyboard(unsigned char key, int x, int y);
};
```

CÓDIGO DE `db.cpp`

```
#include "db.h"



DB::DB() 
{
    camara = new Camara();
}



void DB::initContext(int argc, char** argv)
{
    //Creamos el contexto
    glutInit(&argc, argv);
    glutInitContextVersion(3, 3);
    glutInitContextFlags(GLUT_FORWARD_COMPATIBLE);
    glutInitContextProfile(GLUT_CORE_PROFILE);
    //Definimos el FrameBuffer y creamos la ventana
    glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_DOUBLE | GLUT_RGBA | GLUT_DEPTH);
    glutInitWindowSize(500, 500);
    glutInitWindowPosition(0, 0);
    glutCreateWindow("Prácticas OGL");
    //Cargamos todas las extensiones
    glewExperimental = GL_TRUE;
    GLenum err = glewInit();
    if (GLEW_OK != err)
    {
        std::cout << "Error: " << glewGetErrorString(err) << std::endl;
        exit(-1);
    }
    const GLubyte *oglVersion = glGetString(GL_VERSION);
    std::cout << "This system supports OpenGL Version: " << oglVersion << std::endl;
    //Definimos los callback
    glutReshapeFunc(resize);
    glutIdleFunc(idle);
    glutDisplayFunc(render);
    glutMouseFunc(mouse);
    glutKeyboardFunc(keyboard);
}

void DB::resize(int width, int height)
{
    glViewport(0, 0, width, height);
    DB::camara->setProj(glm::perspective(glm::radians(60.0f), float(width) / float(height), 1.0f, 50.0f));
    glutPostRedisplay();
}

void DB::initOGL()
{
    //Activamos el test de profundidad y establecemos el color del fondo
    glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
    glClearColor(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
    //Indica la orientación de la cara front, configura la etapa de rasterizado y activa el culling
    glFrontFace(GL_CCW);
    glPolygonMode(GL_FRONT_AND_BACK, GL_FILL);
    glEnable(GL_CULL_FACE);
    //Define la matriz de vista y la matriz de proyección
    camara->setProj(camara->getProj() * (glm::perspective(glm::radians(60.0f), 1.0f, 0.1f, 50.0f)));
    camara->getView()[3].z = -6;
}

void DB::idle()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < modelos.size(); i++)
    {
        modelos[i].setModel(glm::rotate(glm::mat4(1), 0.0f, glm::vec3(0, 1, 0))* glm::translate(glm::mat4(1), glm::vec3(0, 0, 3)));
    }
    glutPostRedisplay();
}

void DB::render()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < modelos.size(); i++)
    {
        modelos[i].drawMesh(*(DB::camara));
    }
}

void DB::mainLoop()
{
    glutMainLoop();
}

void DB::addMesh(Mesh modelo)
{
    modelos.push_back(modelo);
}


void DB::mouse(int button, int state, int x, int y)
{

}

void DB::keyboard(unsigned char key, int x, int y)
{

}
```

El problema surge en el método `initContext`, específicamente en las cinco últimas líneas, es decir, en lo referente a los callbacks. Me gustaría saber de qué forma puedo convertir estas funciones en funciones sin miembro.

Answer (score 0):

por lo que veo tu problema esta en las siguientes líneas de la función initContext()

```
glutReshapeFunc(resize);
glutIdleFunc(idle);
glutDisplayFunc(render);
glutMouseFunc(mouse);
glutKeyboardFunc(keyboard);
```

Lo que sucede es que las funciones resize(), idle() render(), mouse() y keyboard() cada una de ellas lleva implícitamente lleva un parámetro extra, el parámetro **this**.
Una forma de solucionar esto, es definir estas funciones como funciones estáticas, con el modificador **static**, pero luego aparece otro problema, es que no puedes acceder a los miembros de la clase, a menos que declares a estos también como estáticos.

Comment: El caso es que si los pongo en static, no puedo alterar las variables de otras clases. Y al tener un vector de Mesh y llamar a un método propio de esta clase para alterar sus componentes, me sale el correspondiente error. Me gustaría saber si hay alguna posibilidad de crear una función que transforme de método de C++ a método de C.

Comment: Lo sé, por eso aclaro al final que si queres acceder a esas variables, tambien deberías declararlas como static (no sólo los métodos).
Quizas otra opción sería contemplar el patrón Singleton.
https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton

Comment: Lo intenté. Pero resultó que me salían varios errores de compilación. Debe ser que hice algo mal... De todas formas, muchas gracias por la ayuda.